# #NAME? error on correct Excel formula

Tags: syntax-error, excel-formula

NAME? error is the output for the formula shown bellow. **$D$6** is a number. However whenever I click inside the formula and press '**intro**' as if the cell had been modified, the formula returns the correct value.

```
=MROUND($D$6-9.1132,1/16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Inserted the Formula with C# and saved it.

```
range.Formula = "=SUMME(A1:C3)";
```

When I opened the workbook it would show me the "#Name?"-Error. Once klicked in the cell manually it showed the correct formula, and when i left the cell it would show the correct calculated value instead of "#Name?"

I found out that it was a localization problem. I use the german Excel, but the formulas via Excel-Com-Interop-Library **have to be inserted in english**!

```
range.Formula = "=SUM(A1:C3)";
```

Once i changed this, everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If **D6** value is less than 9.1132 you have a negative number in the left part. The right part of the formula has positive number, that's why you get the error. Please ensure both parts of your formula have the same sign. [Here is the man page for this.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/mround-HP005209185.aspx)

Comment: D6 value is 106. That's not the case, it would be easier if that were the case; and it would return a NUM error.

Comment: If this function is not available, and returns the #NAME? error, install and load the Analysis ToolPak add-in.

Comment: @AndresPerez, a was able to check the function with D6 value "106". The result was 96.875. Please see the screenshot: http://imgur.com/XIqjxxB

Comment: I know. Please don't treat me as if i didn't know that formula is correct. I know it is correct. The on open failure and having to re-enter the formula is what makes it weird. I know there shouldn't be any error.